# How to deal with float <div>s in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I encountered the following code to deal with float (div)s in HTML . I any one knows how it works .

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.clearfix {display: inline-block;}

/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

Comment: Please explain what is your exact requirement. Also post HTML code or some image explaining the design you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be some sort of polyfill for ie on mac.

it basically makes a pesudo element that is appended inside an element to whichever this class is applied to, however since height is 0, the 'dot' doesn't show up.

`clear:both` makes it so other elements that are in the flow, ie. not floating. will still not stack up next to floating elements. 'both' means clear on both side.